# $f$ continuous at $I : \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L, L \in R$, Prove $\exists x_0 \in I: f(x_0) \leq L$ if $\exists$ minimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f$ continuous in $I = [0, \infty): \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L, L \in \mathbb{R}$

Prove that if $f$ havs a  minimum in $I$, then there is $ x_0 \in I$ such that $ f(x_0) \leq L$

---

### My attempt:

I will try to prove the contra-positive condition:

If $\forall x_0 \in I: L < f(x_0) \Rightarrow f$ doesnt have a minimum in $I$

---

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L: \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists M > 0, \forall x > M: |f(x) - L | < \varepsilon$

If $\forall x_0 \in I: L < f(x_0) \Rightarrow Let \ \gamma = |f(x_0) - L|>0 \Rightarrow f(x_0) = L + \gamma $,

Let $\varepsilon = \gamma/2, \exists M > 0, \forall y > M, y \in I: |f(y) - L| < \varepsilon = \gamma / 2 $

$\Rightarrow  L - \gamma/2< f(y) < L + \gamma /2 < L + \gamma = f(x_0)$

$\Rightarrow \forall x_0 \in I, \exists y \in I: f(y) < f(x_0)$

$\Rightarrow$ No minimum for $f$ at the interval $[0, \infty)$

Corrections? Better ways for proving?

Comment: You can show this too: if $f$ is continuous _on_ $\mathrm{I}$ and $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t) = L,$ then $f$ is a bounded function.

The gist of the proof is that outside a large interval $[0, M],$ $f$ will be between $L-1$ and $L+1,$ and $f$ is bounded on $[0, M].$

Comment: I dont understand you well i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(y)$ be the minimum of $f$. Then  $f(y) \leq f(n)$ for all $n >y$. Let $n \to \infty$ to get $f(y) \leq L$. Take $x_0=y$

Comment: That is smart, thank you.